# Select all non-transparent pixels in a layer

Tags: gimp

I was going around trying to center the contents of a png image with anti-aliasing, and I imported the image into GIMP - but then I realised I didn't know how to select all the non-transparent pixels inside it.

My first thought, and that of many other answers on stack exchange, was to use `Alpha to Selection` - but it doesn't actually select all the *non-transparent* pixels. It has an arbitrary cut-off point, and some pixels with alphas of more than zero weren't selected - of course, that certainly won't work properly if I want to move the selection.

Does anyone know what I'm missing?

Comment: Your question puzzles me. Can't you just move the whole layer?  There is normally no need to make a selection to centre a graphic.

Comment: @BillyK Well then, how can I center it?

Comment: With the move tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The `Select by Color` tool

The tool called `Select by Color` does exactly what is needed to select all the opaque pixels in a layer. All you need to do is to select `Alpha` in the `Select by` dropdown, and drag `Threshold` all the way to the right.
Then, click in any opaque area of the layer, and all the non-transparent pixels will be selected!

So basically, all you need to do is this:

1. Select the `Select by Color` tool.
2. Select `Alpha` from the `Select by` dropdown.
3. Drag `Threshold` all the way to the right - that'll probably be 255.
4. Click on any non-transparent pixel in the layer.
5. And voila! All the non-transparent pixels in the layer are selected.

Comment: Exactly, and if the background isn't 100% transparent, it is selected. My technique works form the other end, you select the pixels that are exactly as transparent as the background, and then take the other ones.

Comment: can we do same in photoshop? if so how

Answer (score 5):

Alpha to selection selects all the pixels but proportionally to their opacity (the "marching ants" are telling you where the selection level goes from `>50%` to `<50%`). This selection is fine from many things, but not to copy/paste the contents(*). If you want to have them fully selected you have to `Select > Save to channel`, threshold the saved channel with a value of 1, and then re-create a selection from the channel (right-click, and `Channel to selection`). But this is not necessary, to center you contents there are at least two techniques:

### Method #1:

`Layer > Crop to content`: this makes the smallest layer that contains all the non fully transparent pixels. You can then center this.

### Method #2:

If you want a selection, use the Color selector, set `Select by:  Alpha`, check `Select transparent areas` and set the threshold to 0. Then click on the layer's background. This will only select the fully transparent pixels. `Select > Invert` and you have the selection that you originally sought.

Also, keep in mind that centering is somewhat visual when you have semi-transparent pixels on the edges. This is why in many fonts, characters with a round base (C,G,O,Q,U) slightly extend below the baseline.

(*) Because a half-opaque pixel, being half-opaque, will be half-selected, and therefore half-copied. When pasted, the half-copy of the half-opaque will be quarter-opaque which is much more transparent. This makes things look thinner.

Comment: Neither of those worked, but I didn't know about the `Select by Color` tool - so thanks for that! I tried doing something a bit different from Method #2, and that worked. 
Edit: Oh wait, Method #2 did work - but `Select transparent areas` needed to be on.

Comment: OK, fixed answer